# How to export table schema into a csv file

Tags: python, sql, csv, pyspark, export-to-csv

Basically, I want to export a hive table's schema into a csv file. I can create a datframe and then show its schema but I want to write its schema to a csv file. Seems pretty simple but it wont work.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: You can get the column names from `testing.columns` and the data types from `testing.dtypes`. The full schema is available in `testing.schema`. Transforming those into a `csv` file is fairly trivial, but it depends on the desired output.

Comment: Do you have to do it via spark only? There is much easier way via shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase you wanna do it within Hive console. This is how you do it

```
hive>
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/user1/file1'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
SELECT * from tablename
```

And then in Unix

```
[user1]$
cat file1/* > file1.csv
zip file1 file1.csv
```